# C preprocessor and "_asm _emit" directive

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, c-preprocessor, inline-assembly

I'm trying to achieve a boolean arithmetic along with the `_asm _emit` in Visual Studio 2015, want to insert some x64 opcodes in x86 program, I must do a lot of `mov` to memory commands, so I tried to make some kind of macro, which take the address and emits in little-endian so:

```
#define EmitDword(x)\
{\
    _asm _emit (x & 0x000000FF) \
    _asm _emit ((x >> 8) & 0x000000FF) \
    _asm _emit ((x >> 16) & 0x000000FF) \
    _asm _emit ((x >> 24) & 0x000000FF) \
}
```

But I get an error `inline assembler syntax error in 'first operand';`
The idea is, to pass an address of a variable to the macro, so it would be emitted directly into machine code, then I could do something like this:

```
 #define EmitDword(x)\
 {\
        _asm _emit (x & 0x000000FF) \
        _asm _emit ((x >> 8) & 0x000000FF) \
        _asm _emit ((x >> 16) & 0x000000FF) \
        _asm _emit ((x >> 24) & 0x000000FF) \
 }

/* mov qword ptr [addr],reg  */
#define X64_MovToMem(addr,reg)\
{\
  _asm _emit 0x48\
  _asm _emit 0x89\ 
  _asm _emit reg\ 
  _asm _emit 0x25\
  EmitDword(addr)\ 
}

#define _rax 4
void test()
{
    DWORD64 someData;
    X64_MovToMem(&someData,_rax);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the emitting of non-constant values using preprocessor inline assembly?

Comment: No, every byte you emit into the compiler's asm output has to be a compile-time constant.  I doubt you're going to have any luck creating useful x86-64 code with this attempt to work around MSVC only supporting `_asm` in 32-bit mode.  You should probably just write functions in asm and call them from C++, because there's no way to tell the compiler about the actions of any instructions you're inserting.

Comment: Also note that addresses are link-time constants, not truly compile-time, so chopping up the address with a macro isn't going to work: the compiler and assembler can't know each byte separately, and need to just leave space and put a relocation in the symbol table of the object file.  The value will be filled in at link time by the linker.

Comment: If you just need asm instructions as data, and are encoding them yourself, why not use a struct and memcpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to mess around with 64-bit code in a 32-bit process to access the 64-bit Process Environment Block. You can obtain its address using 32-bit code, and it's located within the 32-bit address space. You'd only need to use 64-bit code if you need to access memory allocated outside the 32-bit address space, and I don't think Windows will ever do that in a 32-bit process.

If you really did need to have a 64-bit function in a 32-bit executable there's a better way of doing it than using the `_asm _emit`. The first thing to do is to write your entire 64-bit function in plain assembly and assemble it with an normal external assembler.  For example, here's a function that reads from a 64-bit pointer in MASM syntax:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
__read64ptr:
    mov rax, [rsp + 8]
    mov eax, [rax]
    mov edx, [rax + 4]
    retf
_TEXT   ENDS
    END
```

This simple function takes a 64-bit pointer as an argument on the stack. A 64-bit value located at address pointed to is put into EAX and EDX.  This function is meant to called with a 32-bit far call instruction.

Note that the return value takes up two 32-bit stack slots, one for the 32-bit offset of the return address and another for the selector.  Despite the fact that the RETF instruction is executed in 64-bit mode, it uses a 32-bit stack size by default (unlike the 64-bit near RET instruction) and will work correctly with the 32-bit far return address saved on the stack.

Unfortunately we can't use this assembly file directly with the tools provided with Visual Studio. The 64-bit version of MASM only creates 64-bit object files, and the linker won't let us mix 32-bit and 64-bit object files. It should be possible to assemble 64-bit code into a 32-bit object using NASM and link with Microsoft's linker, but it's possible to use the code indirectly using only Microsoft's tools.

To do that, assemble the file and copy the machine code manually into a C array that lives in the `.text` section:

```
#pragma code_seg(push, ".text")
#pragma code_seg(pop)
char const __declspec(allocate(".text")) _read64ptr[] = {
    0x48, 0x8b, 0x44, 0x24, 0x08,   /* mov rax, [rsp + 8] */
    0x8b, 0x00,                     /* mov eax. [rax] */
    0x8b, 0x50, 0x04,               /* mov edx, [rax + 4] */
    0xcb                            /* retf */
};
```

To call it you just need to use code like this:

```
struct {
    void const *offset;
    unsigned short selector;
} const _read64ptr_ind = { _read64ptr, 0x33 };

unsigned long long
read64ptr(unsigned long long address) {
    unsigned long long value;
    _asm {
        push    DWORD PTR [address + 4]
        push    DWORD PTR [address]
        call    FWORD PTR [_read64ptr_ind]
        add     esp, 8
        mov     DWORD PTR [value], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [value + 4], edx
    }
    return value;
}
```

The indirection with `_read64ptr_ind` is necessary because there's no way to write `call 33h:_read64ptr` in Microsoft inline assembly. Also note that the 64-bit code selector `0x33` is hard coded in this example, hopefully it won't change.

Here's an example that uses the above code to read the address of the 64-bit PEB from the 64-bit TEB (even though both are located in the 32-bit address space):

```
unsigned long long
readgsqword(unsigned long off) {
    unsigned long long value;
    _asm {
        mov edx, [off]
        mov eax, gs:[edx]
        mov edx, gs:[edx + 4]
        mov DWORD PTR [value], eax
        mov DWORD PTR [value + 4], edx
    }
    return value;
}

int
main() {
    printf("32-bit TEB address %08lx\n",
           __readfsdword(offsetof(NT_TIB, Self)));
    printf("32-bit PEB address %08lx\n", __readfsdword(0x30));
    unsigned long long teb64 = readgsqword(offsetof(NT_TIB64, Self));
    printf("64-bit TEB address %016llx\n", teb64);
    printf("64-bit PEB address %016llx\n", readgsqword(0x60));
    printf("64-bit PEB address %016llx\n", read64ptr(teb64 + 0x60));
}
```

Running it on my computer generates the following output:

```
32-bit TEB address 7efdd000
32-bit PEB address 7efde000
64-bit TEB address 000000007efdb000
64-bit PEB address 000000007efdf000
64-bit PEB address 000000007efdf000
```

As you can see all the structures can be accessed using 32-bit pointers and without any 64-bit code. In particular, the example shows how to obtain a 32-bit pointer to the 64-bit PEB using only 32-bit code.

A final note, there's no guarantee that Windows will handle 64-bit code running in a 32-bit process correctly. If an interrupt happens to occur at any time while executing the 64-bit code the process may end up crashing.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I will accept this answer, since is the best, and it seems the only thing really good to do is to write x64 masm code, assemble it and copy-pase directly. The thing is that i need to access x64 memory locations. I want to loop trough PEB_LDR_DATA, and on windows 10 its address is x64 bit. Also some entries with wchar buffers, of loaded module names (UNICODE_STRING64) have x64 addresses too. I have one more question, can you explain about possible system interrupt that might break wow64 process execution if it fires?

Comment: @Vlad: Since the kernel thinks it's a 32-bit process, it might return to user-space in 32-bit compat mode, even if the interrupt happened while user-space was in 64-bit long mode.

Comment: You might be able to emit the right encoding for a direct far-call using `push whatever` / `db 9Ah` / `dd _read64ptr` / `dw 33h` in MSVC inline-asm.  Unlike the OP's attempt to chop up a link-time value at compile-time, that should let the linker take care of filling in the 4-byte address.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unfortunately, for whatever reason, the DB, DD, etc.. directives don't work in Microsoft inline assembly. You need to use `_emit` instead, but it only works with byte values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but what you are trying to do makes no sense.

- "insert some x64 opcodes in x86 program" - If it is an x86 program, it isn't going to run x64 opcodes.
- "_asm _emit (x & 0x000000FF)" - Have you read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b80826t.aspx) for emit?  You can only emit bytes, not C code.
- "emit emit emit emit" - Why do you think that doing 4 writes of 1 byte each (which this code doesn't do anyway) will be faster than doing 1 write of 4 bytes?
- "Is there any way to achieve the emitting of non-constant values" - If you are using emit, then you would need to know what register the value you are trying to write is currently stored in (something which is almost impossible to accomplish since the compiler might use different registers every time the code changes, and the value may not even be in a register).

I'm trying to look past how you are writing this to solve your original problem.  However:

I realize that there is a tendency to think that "asm is faster."  But remember that C code gets translated to assembler.  The compiler is already generating asm code that is almost certainly much more efficient than something you can cobble together via emit.

And if using 64bit instructions is going to produce better code (which is certainly possible), you should build a 64bit executable.

If you are convinced that you can create asm code that is more efficient then the C compiler, consider creating an entire asm routine, then call it from your C code.  Note that you will not be able to link x64 assembler into your x86 program.

Comment: I think he's trying to emit the 4 bytes of an address in little-endian order, not emit an instruction that actually computes `x & 0x000000FF`.  I agree it doesn't appear to make sense, though.  I'm not totally sure he wants to run the machine code emitted, given that he says "emit x64 opcodes into an x86 program", which is why I suggested just using a struct or something.  I thought about posting an answer, but I didn't think the question made enough sense to be answerable.

Comment: His remark about `i must do a lot of mov to memory commands` sounds like the intent is to improve performance.  The belief that "everyone knows that asm is faster than C" combined with limited understanding of how asm works could produce a question like this.  Trying to use x64 would be another attempt to make things faster.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was trying to find a way of interpreting the question other than the one where the answer is "of course not, that can't possibly work".  But I think you might be right, based on that sentence in the question.

Comment: Im trying to execute x64 code in context of x86 process on runtime. It is possible, by doing the far jump to the selector `0x33` which stands for x64 code segment.

Comment: Is this because you think calling x64 code from x86 code is cool and you want to try it?  Or is your hope to make things faster?  Or is there some other goal?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd no, i want to make some hacks in 64 peb of the process

Comment: @Vlad How about you write the amd64 parts in pure assembly using asm files instead of inline assembly?